# Core Data entity relationship hierarchy

Tags: ios, entity-framework, core-data

I would like to setup entities and relationships in core data to handle this situation:

There are teams, and each team can have multiple photos of the team and multiple players on the team...but also each player can have multiple photos.  (Sorry, it looks like I need more reputation points before I can post the image of the relationship.)

If this is possible, I'm not sure I know how to set it up properly.  In the Photo entity, I believe I can setup the "forPlayer" and "forTeam" relationships to be optional.  Doing so would allow me to set one or the other so that a photo is associated with either a Team or a Player.

Will this work?

Now what if I associate a photo with a Player *and* a Team?  If I do that, and if I have cascade delete enabled, will that present any problems if a Team or Player is removed?

Comment: You should be able to link to an image uploaded somewhere else.

Comment: For the cascade part, they shouldn't both be cascade - there should be 1 owner. So you probably shouldn't use cascade at all in this case.

Comment: Why not create a dummy base class that player and team inherit from. Then it wont matter and you can cascade as well.

Comment: I suppose I could model it with Team<<-->PhotoForTeam and then separately Team<<-->Player<<-->PhotoForPlayer and the cascade deletes would work, but I was hoping to use just one entity for photos.

Comment: Thanks @rfrittelli...my example is oversimplified though.  In reality I have several layers of hierarchy and many different entities so I don't know if a base/parent class would work (or don't know how I would set that up).

Comment: What happens if you have a photo with two or more players in it, but not the full team ?  Do you want to associated it with all the players in it ? 
Also presumably over time the team changes (well the players that make up the team), do you need to track who is on the team at a given point in time ?

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, excellent questions.  My implementation is very simple however, and these are not concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would distinguish between `PlayerPhoto` and `TeamPhoto` as separate entities. This is logical also because in the real world these photos would be something quite different. (When modelling entities it is always advisable to try to get as concrete as possible.)

Both `PlayerPhoto` and `TeamPhoto` could inherit from a `Photo` entity that encapsulate the data of photos. Presumably you would have something like a `fileName` or `url` attribute that denotes the location of the photo. (Do not store the photos as `NSData` in the database, as this is only advisable for small images, such as thumbnails.).

If you want to use the same actual photo for both team and player, you could still have two separate entities, even if they refer to the same physical photo in terms of name/url. Cascading should just work as expected while leaving all photo files intact.

As for deleting unneeded photos, you could either account for this when deleting the photo entity, or alternatively have a cleanup method that removes photos not referenced in your object graph.